# how to send mail from .net?

Tags: email

i wrote the method as below i got the error as The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. pls help me

```
SendMail("xyz@gmail.com","hi","heloo");

public bool SendMail(string toMailAddress, string mailSubject, string mailMessage)
    {

         string smtphost ="smtp.gmail.com";
            int smtpport = 100;
            string smtpuser ="xyz";
            string smtppwd = "xyz";
            SmtpClient client = null;



            string MessageBody = string.Empty;
            try
            {

                message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(smtpuser);
                message.To.Add(toMailAddress);
                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Subject = mailSubject;
                message.Body = mailMessage.ToString();



                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Host = smtphost;

                client.Port = smtpport;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpuser, smtppwd);
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string x = ex.Message;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: Could you print the *toMailAddress* variable and see if it is a correct email address?

Comment: Also, you are doing this **string smtpuser ="xyz";** and then you use it as an email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "from" user must be in the form of a valid email address.

```
message.From = new MailAddress(smtpuser);
```

Also, you will need to use the MailAddress constructor for the .To property as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try, with port as 25 and IsSSLEnabled as true since gmail server is SSL enabled

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the toMailAddress, and smtpuser are valid email address.
Try, Using smtpport = 587; provided by Gmail for Outgoing Mails (SMTP).
Hope this will make it work fine. Please list out the errors you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work. What i have done are

1. proper smtphost
2. proper smtpport - 587
3. Enable SSL
4. set UseDefaultCredentials to false before setting the credentials
5. set DeliveryMethod

```
 public static bool SendMail(string toMailAddress, string mailSubject, string   mailMessage)
    {            
        string smtphost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        int smtpport = 587;
        string smtpuser = "youremail@gmail.com";
        string smtppwd = "password";

        SmtpClient client = null;



        string MessageBody = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(smtpuser);                
            message.To.Add(toMailAddress);
            message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            message.Subject = mailSubject;
            message.Body = mailMessage.ToString();
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = smtphost;                
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Port = smtpport;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpuser, smtppwd);

            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string x = ex.InnerException.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        return true;

    }
```